# How to stop the wheel of fortune at a particular segment smoothly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I have created this wheel of fortune game in reactJS. It is completely random and worked correctly till now. I was able to catch the segment where it stopped but now I am receiving the winning segment also from backend side so I have to stop this wheel exactly at that segment.

I thought that may be if I compare the actual winner value with the current segment running in downtime (that is when it is getting slowed down) and then suddenly stop it if the actual winner value is equal to the current segment by making angle equal to zero but it is not stopping and still kept moving. if I add this snippet, it will work but it will just stop suddenly and user may think that it is fixed.

```
if(this.state.winner === this.winningSegment){

      progress = 1;
            }else{

      progress = duration / this.downTime;
            }
```

[code editor link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lsrq9i)

```
 onTimerTick = () => {
    this.frames++;

    this.draw();
    console.log(frames);

    var duration = new Date().getTime() - this.spinStart;
    var progress = 0;
    var finished = false;

    if (duration < this.upTime) {
      progress = duration / this.upTime;
      this.angleDelta = this.maxSpeed * Math.sin((progress * Math.PI) / 2);
    } else {
      progress = duration / this.downTime;
      this.angleDelta =
        this.maxSpeed * Math.sin((progress * Math.PI) / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
      if (this.winningSegment === this.state.winner) {
        this.angleDelta = 0;
        this.angleCurrent = 0;
      }
      if (progress >= 1) finished = true;
    }

    this.angleCurrent += this.angleDelta;
    while (this.angleCurrent >= Math.PI * 2)
      // Keep the angle in a reasonable range
      this.angleCurrent -= Math.PI * 2;

    if (finished) {
      console.log(this.state);
      this.setState({
        isFinished: true
      });
      clearInterval(this.timerHandle);
      this.timerHandle = 0;
      this.angleDelta = 0;
    }
  };
```

Comment: It works quirky to me, it looks like it's getting reset each time. So your issue is about identifying the active segment in the wheel at any given point? Cause if you get that right, you can compare it with the server result and apply whatever logic to slow it down.

Comment: @Ravenous actually it was getting reset because I was trying to stop it by comparing actual winning segment with the current segment by making the current angle to zero but it is not working and instead of getting stop, it is getting reset.
I am able to identify the active point correctly.

Comment: `if (this.winningSegment === this.state.winner) {
        this.angleDelta = 0;
        this.angleCurrent = 0;
      }else{

    this.angleCurrent += this.angleDelta;
        while (this.angleCurrent >= Math.PI * 2)
      // Keep the angle in a reasonable range
      this.angleCurrent -= Math.PI * 2;

      }`
so if I remove if part from the above statement, it will become smooth again.